# Error in convert view to image in android

Tags: android

Here when i problem convert view to image in android then i am facing an error and close the application but when i write hardcoded fields for createbitmap function then it save black image in sd card ...

```
  public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView (View v) {
        Bitmap b,bitmap;
    int iwidth = 1435;
    int iheight=435;
        try
        {b = Bitmap.createBitmap(iwidth,  iheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
         //error  in next line 
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
         return b;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("error", e.getMessage());
            return bitmap=null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, some shots in the dark:

-Are you sure the view is not null and has a width and height that you can retrieve at the time of the call? I would have a check for that at the beginning- throw an error or return a null if the View v is null.

-The method getWidth() returns a *final* int. I'm not a java expert but maybe that is messing something up, so try setting iwidth and iheight to getWidth() and getHeight() and then see if it works.

Comment: yes dear i am passing the view as a parameter of loadBitmapFromView function and return the bitmap
actually the upper side code is like that  :
    View drawView;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas;
    drawView = new Drawing(this);

Comment: You said you have an error on the line with 'v.getWidth(), v.getHeight()' so I am assuming that is the problem. The only difference between the line that works and the line that doesn't is that the breaking one you get the height/width from the view. So debug the crap out of that line and see why it is failing. I just gave two suggestions.